# Command Line Arguments for two .txt files

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I have the following program which simply reads two matrices from .txt files into 2D arrays. And I run it from Developer Command Prompt for VS2012 like first picture

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;


namespace Assignment3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[,] matrix1 = new int[3, 3]; int[,] matrix2 = new int[3, 3]; int[,] matrix3 = new int[3, 3];
            int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
            #region Reading Matrices From Files
           
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Matrix1.txt");
            
           
            foreach (var row in text.Split('\n'))
            {
                j = 0;
                foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
                {
                    matrix1[i, j] = int.Parse(col.Trim());
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Execution Starts Here");
            Console.WriteLine("\nMatrix1 Has been read from file Matrix1.txt...\n");
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(String.Format("{0}\t", matrix1[i,j]));
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            
            string text2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Matrix2.txt");
            i = 0;

            foreach (var row in text2.Split('\n'))
            {
                j = 0;
                foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
                {
                    matrix2[i, j] = int.Parse(col.Trim());
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nMatrix2 Has been read from file Matrix2.txt...\n");
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(String.Format("{0}\t", matrix2[i, j]));
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            #endregion
```

[image]
Here what I am intended to do is to execute the program.exe with files names also (means giving the files names at execution time) like as in the second picture.

[image]

I think it has to do with some thing like number of command arguments. anyone help me please.

Comment: Hint: `void Main(string[] args)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `string[] args` part of the `Main` method contains any command line arguments passed to your application. You can access the file names through `args[0]` and `args[1]`.

**Edit:** Just to add, you can specify the command line arguments to use when debugging/running your app from Visual Studio by viewing the properties for your project (select the project in Solution explorer and press `Alt+Enter`) and setting them in the `Command Line Arguments` field under the `Debug` tab.

**Edit:** In response to your question in the comment: where you have

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Matrix1.txt");
```

you have hard coded the file name as Matrix1.text. If you want the ability to specify file names at run time, one option is to pass them as command line arguments. These command line arguments can be accessed with the `args[]` parameter in your main method. args[0] contains the first parameter value, args[1] contains the second and so on. So the line above could be replaced by

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(args[0]);
```

It is worth noting that people typically have a validation section at the top of the `Main` method that confirms the user has passed the expected number of arguments and that they are of the expected types. If there are any exceptions it is common to display a usage message and then exit the application.

Comment: Ok now i have a bit of sense for this, but how to assign these args[0] and args[1] the .txt files. according to this code

Comment: I've updated the answer to give you a bit more detail.

Comment: really well done that's what I wanted.  thanks mate